# UART isolation with opto-coupler

Tags: serial, opto-isolator, gpio, 3.3v

I've got two devices running on different power sources and different grounds.
I'd like to connect them together through a Serial connection (UART TTL) at baud rate 460800.

Both devices have 3.3V UART GPIO but also a 5V output that can be used. Output current is 5mA.

I've finally achieve to create those two schematics but I'm not certain they are correct.

1. **Case 1**: Using [HCPL-7723](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-0643EN) opto and a voltage divider (to get 3.3V output):

[image]

2. **Case 2**: Using [H11L1M](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809221211_onsemi-H11L1M-_C16587.pdf) opto where eveything is 3.3V:

[image]

Case 1 can transfer data up to 50 MB/s and case 2 up to 1 MB/s. Case 2's elements are cheaper and more common.

Could you help me to validate these two schematics ?

Comment: What baud rate do you intend to use, and what is the output drive capability of your devices?

Comment: Current max baud rate is 460800 and output current is 5mA.

Comment: You have not explained (even in your previous question) why you need opto-isolators to begin with, and what is the communication distance? Why can't the grounds be simply be connected together, why they must be kept separate? You may be trying to add optocouplers for no reason at all. What are the power sources and where else the boards are connected?

Comment: One of the devices is unmanaged and can potentially output high current. Communication distance is 10 centimeters. Both devices cannot be connected together for security reason.

Comment: @Manitoba What does it mean when you say the other device is unmanaged and can potentially output high current. How it could do it? Security or safety? Please draw a diagram about the system.

Comment: One side is publicly accessible while the other is not. Anyone can access that side and change the cable to whatever they want to. I need to protect the second device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both schematics are correct.

The H11L1 is inverting, like most optocouplers. But you can avoid having to invert the signal in software by driving the LED from the anode, i.e., supply to pin 1, and TX to pin 2. (In that case, you also save power because the LED is off when the UART is idle = high.)

> [image: H11L1 driven by the anode]
> <sub>Credit goes to Justme for resistor values.</sub>

The H11L1 is also made by other manufacturers.

I doubt your signals will be faster than 1 Mbit/s (an asynchronous protocol like UART would not work at high speeds in any case), so I see no reason to choose the HCPL-7723.

Comment: Why UART would not work at faster than 1Mbps? I've been using 3Mbps for years as it was the fastest the USB UART supported. Recently I made a bord with USB UART that supported 12Mbps and it works fine too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean something like that ? https://i.imgur.com/DGCxMJ3.png

Comment: @Justme UARTs are sensitive to the clock frequency. I have no doubt that 12 Mbps works in the typical case, but I would not guarantee it.

Comment: @Manitoba Stolen, thanks!

Comment: So with H11L1, when TXA is H, RXB will be H too. Seems an easier way to make it !
But HCP-7723 is not inverting but is a bit too fast for my uses.

Comment: @CL Weird misconception. UART is not sensitive to clock frequency, as that's the whole point of it. UART easily tolerates +/- 1 to 2 % difference in baud rates between two devices, and since that's percentage, it applies equally at any baud rate, both 9600 bps and at 12 Mbps for example.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the cheaper and more common Case 2, but with changes.

Change the LED to be on when GPIO is low. The 1k LED resistor should work, but it does not hurt to have smaller resistance to allow for more current and make the LED turn on and off faster. Maybe around 470 ohms, maybe 330 to 680 ohms range.

Then the receiver side is way too slow with th 4k7 resistor. The datasheet uses 270 ohms and still the typical turn on and off times are 1 to 4 microseconds. This datasheet does not show curves based on pull-up resistance, but using the 270 ohm suggested value, they should be approximately symmetrical. The problem is, 921600 bps might not work and you need to use lower baud rate, perhaps 250 kbps due to the 4 uS turn-on and turn-off time.

Comment: Do you mean something like that ? https://i.imgur.com/3diBgKA.png
I understand the drawback of using high resistors.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. About HCPL-7723 case, do I also need to lower the resistor values ?